# Jquery DataTables Live DOM Ordering on Checkbox column not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a DataTable in my .NET Core application which has a checkbox column. I would like to be able to sort/order the table by checkbox value using the arrow buttons in the table header. In order to achieve this I have used the code from the DataTables Live DOM Ordering example here: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

However, the column re-ordering does not work. If I inspect the elements I can see that there is something happening to the  elements as they flash, however the order of the rows is not changing.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <table id="airportsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IsoCode</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>TimezoneName</th>
                <th>TimezoneStandardName</th>
                <th>
                    Required
                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckbox" value="false" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{ foreach (var airport in airportList) //Index , update after iteration, so that non-model data can be attached
                {
                    string iso = airportList[tableIndex].IsoCode; 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label id="isoCode">@airportList[tableIndex].IsoCode</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="name">@airportList[tableIndex].Name</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id="timeZoneName">@airportList[tableIndex].TimeZoneName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label id ="timeZoneStandardName">@airportList[tableIndex].TimeZoneStandardName</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@airportList[tableIndex].Required" id="requiredCheckbox" onclick="requiredChanged(this, '@airportList[tableIndex].IsoCode' )" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    tableIndex++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
        } );
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
         var airportsTable = $('#airportsTable').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 50,
            "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
            ]
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your table after your columns section:

`"columnDefs": [
        { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox", targets: 5 }
    ]`

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderDataType